# How to avoid duplication of events in Android Calendar?

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-contentresolver

I get a list of events (of a week) from server through an API call and my app needs to sync them to calendar in device. The events can be updated or deleted on server without any intercations from app. And I need to sync them to calendar on every refresh of screen.

To make my events on calendar up to date with my server, I'm performing following actions on refresh:

1. Deleting all the events of a given week from calendar.
2. Then inserting the events that I get from the server.

   ```
   public static void deleteAllEventsInWeekOfCalendar(Activity activity, int calId, long weekStartTimeMillis, long weekEndTimeMillis) {
       try {
       Uri eventUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
       String[] projection = new String[]{Events._ID, Events.TITLE, Events.DTSTART, Events.DESCRIPTION};
       String whereClause = Events.CALENDAR_ID + "=" + calId +
               " AND " + Events.DTSTART + " >= " + weekStartTimeMillis +
               " AND " + Events.DTSTART + " <= " + weekEndTimeMillis +
               " AND " + Events.DESCRIPTION + " LIKE '% Added by MyApp'";

       Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(eventUri, projection, whereClause, null, Events.DTSTART);
       if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           Log.v("HowMany", cursor.getCount() + " matching events Found");
           int numOfDeleted = 0;
           do {
               try {
                   String event_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]));
                   int numOfRowsDeleted = activity.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventUri, Long.parseLong(event_id)), null, null);
                   if (numOfRowsDeleted == 1) {
                       ++numOfDeleted;
                   }
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           } while (cursor.moveToNext());
           cursor.close();
           Log.v("HowMany", numOfDeleted + " deleted");
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   ```

And here is my code to insert all events to calendar:

```
 public static void doAddCalendarEvent(MyEvent myEvent, Activity activity, int calendarId) {
    try {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        String desc = myEvent.getDesc();
        desc += "\n\n Added by MyApp";

        ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Events.DTSTART, myEvent.getEventStartTime());
        values.put(Events.DTEND, myEvent.getEventEndTime());
        values.put(Events.TITLE, myEvent.getTitle());
        values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, desc);
        values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId);
        values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, myEvent.getLocation());
        values.put(Events.STATUS, Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED);
        values.put(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
        if (hasAlarm) {
            values.put(Events.HAS_ALARM, true);
        }
        values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        long eventId = 0;
        Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
        if (uri != null) {
            eventId = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            Log.v(TAG, "INSERTED EVENT ID=>" + eventId + "--->" + startDate);
        }
        if (hasAlarm) {
            setReminder(cr, reminderValue, eventId);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Issue : Sometimes The events are duplicating on calendar. How do I avoid the duplication? Where Am'I going wrong? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using a Sync Adapter to interface with the Calendar.

The Sync Adapter has two important methods:

`onPerformSync(...)`, and
`onSyncCanceled(...)`

`onPerformSync` is called whenever you make a `ContentResolver.requestSync` call or if automatic sync is set to true.

While executing, `onPerformSync` can be interrupted by Android. This can happen if the device is running low on resources of if your app is not in the foreground anymore.

When interupted, the Sync Adapter will stop execution where it's at and will call `onSyncCanceled`. The default behavior of the Sync Adapter is to retry the failed sync messages the first chance it gets. So if your app manages to grab onto OS resources again, it will replay the interrupted sync message.

It is possible that some of your messages are being fully processed and, just before `onPerformSync` is about to complete, the Sync Adapter is interrupted. At this point you managed to save the event, however, the Sync Adapter believes that the sync failed, and therefore will replay the same message again the next time it tries to sync.

I am not sure if you are syncing one event at a time so I can't offer a definitive solution. However, what you can do is change the default behaviour of the Sync Adapter to stop it from replaying "failed" messages.

`Bundle extras = new Bundle();
...
extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_DO_NOT_RETRY, true);
CalendarConstants.AUTHORITY, true);
ContentResolver.requestSync(mAccount, CalendarConstants.AUTHORITY, extras);`

In `OnSyncCanceled`, you can do some light checks to make sure the message succeeded, i.e. is present in the calendar's events table. If not, then manually replay it. If it is present, the SyncAdapter will simply move on to the next message, and you won't get any duplicates.

Alternatively, you could make sure all operations within `onPerformSync` are atomic.